# flot pie chart not showing value 1 in pie label

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flot

I am trying to plot a flot pie chart the problem is when i am plotting the all other values are shown on the pie label but the value "1" is not showing..

**pie chart options**

```
var plot = $.plot("#" + divId, graphData, {
    series : {
        pie : {
            show : true,
            label : {
                show : true,
                radius : 2 / 3,
                formatter : labelFormatter,
                threshold : 0.1
            }
        }
    },
    zoom : {
        interactive : false
    },
    pan : {
        interactive : false
    },
    grid : {
        hoverable : true,
        clickable : true
    }
});


 function labelFormatter(label, series) {
  return "<div style='font-size:8pt; text-align:center; padding:2px;     color:white;'>" + series.data[0][1] + "</div>";
 }
```

**my data**

```
[
    {data:2,label:"xxxx"},{data:1,label:"xxxx"},
    {data:2,label:"xxxx"},data:1,label:"xxxx"},
    {data:2,label:"xxxx"},data:6,label:"xxxx"}
]
```

[image: screenshot also attached here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is caused by the `threshold: 0.1` option which suppresses labels for pieces with less less `0.1` of the total value. Since your total value is 14, all pieces with less then 1.4 have no label. Remove the option to show all labels.